# git merge request shows changes from another merge request

Tags: git, rebase

My merge request shows changes from another merge request and on gitlab I see target branch (master) is n commits behind. I tried git rebase master and also git pull --rebase. Still no change in above mentioned problem. Can someone please help?

Comment: What branch did the other merge request merge into?

Comment: Other branch merged into master and I was trying to rebase with master.  I kind of got solution for this problem that  I need to force push which overrides commits to remote branch and then master is not n commits behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment I would recommend following this specific workflow

- Go to your master branch and do a `git pull`
- Switch back to your branch you are merging and do `git rebase origin/master -i`
- Solve any conflicts that arise and fix any commits as needed
- After the rebase is completed do a `git push origin [your branch name] --force`

This should solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, I followed these steps and that worked. Thanks!